# Query date range?

Tags: google-app-maker

Trying to preform a date range query on a datasource example:

```
query.where = 'TransactionDate BETWEEN: StartDate AND EndDate';
```

This is what I get:

> Unexpected input at ': StartDate AND EndDate'.
>   Error: Unexpected input at ': StartDate AND EndDate'. at datasources.

I was assuming this would work similarly to a MySQL query:

```
WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN "2012-03-15" AND "2012-03-31";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use real SQL query you need to go with [Calculated SQL model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#sql_calculated_model). With `query.where = ...` you are setting App Maker's [Query Builder](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_builder) expression that supports limited set of operations. I think your Query Builder expression will look similar to this:

`TransactionDate >= :StartDate AND TransactionDate <= :EndDate`

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I should have caught that in the documentation.